# Is it commonly accepted using the slash to mean "as well as", rather than "or"?

Tags: orthography, slash

> I hope this is the end of blind *US/UK* support for a state with a shocking record of human rights. ([BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/haveyoursay/2010/03/what_next_for_usisrael_relatio.html))

As is well known, the most common use of the *slash* is to link words which are alternative, as in, as an instance, "Everyone must submit his/her name."

But, is the above a general convention? Or, is there a regional difference between the U.S., Britain, Australia and New Zealand usage?

I know, as John Lawler says, that there is neither standard English nor international English, but wouldn't be better to replace the slash with an hyphen in the above BBC's sentence in order to avoid confusion among readers, at least in an international context?

> I hope this is the end of blind *US-UK* support for a state with a shocking record of human rights.

Comment: "Is it commonly accepted using the slash to mean 'as well as'?" Uh! Why would this question be "opinion based"?

Comment: The slash always means *or*.

Comment: @tchrist, I love to hear this from you, but, then, the BBC usage is wrong without further concerns about  possible regional differences?

Comment: I don’t know about all that, but I agree that it would be better written as *US–UK* if it means both.

Comment: _Or_ has several meanings, and the slash is often used to indicate one of a range of terms that can be used for a concept: _One may speak of the mind/psyche/soul/persona of a human, but ..._

Answer (score 4):

In §6.104, "Slashes to signify alternatives," the Chicago Manual of Style says:

> A slash most commonly signifies alternatives. In certain contexts it
>   is a convenient (if somewhat informal) shorthand for *or*. It is also
>   used for alternative spellings or names. Where one or more of the
>   terms separated by slashes is an open compound, a space before and
>   after the slash can be helpful.
>
> - he/she
> - his/her
> - and/or
> - Hercules/Heracles
> - Margaret/Meg/Maggie
> - World War I / First World War
>
> Occasionally a slash can signify *and*—though still usually conveying
>   a sense of alternatives.
>
> - an insertion/deletion mutation
> - an MD/PhD program
> - a Jekyll/Hyde personality

I read the OP's sentence to mean "US *and* UK support" -- although it should be noted that its use appears in a *comment* to the BBC article, and as such can't be considered standard (i.e. professionally produced and edited) writing.

As its use in this case lacks the sense of "conveying alternatives," I can endorse the OP's suggestion to use "US-UK support" instead. However, using a slash to mean *and* is unambiguous to me, and I personally wouldn't quibble about its use here *not* conveying a choice between the US and the UK.

Answer (score 1):

On the West Coast of the US, the slash has always indicated an "'and' or 'or'" statement in my experience.  When dealing with people from the East Coast however, I've seen it used more commonly as an 'or' statement.

In regards to my experience, I would assume it's entirely regional.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gnawme says, the term "US/UK" "appears in a *comment* to [a] BBC article".  The comment as a whole is very badly written.  As the comments on the BBC website are probably fairly transient, I am reproducing it below exactly as it stands:

> At 13:18 16th Mar 2010, [name] wrote:
>
> I hope this is the end of blind US/UK support for a state with a shocking record of
> human rights.
> Lets remember that if israel gets away with this they are literally destroying any arab
> hope of a capital in jerusalem. Therefor ripping apart any hope of a just peace.
> They would also be breaking international law, and be liable, justly, to face international
> sanctions.
> its a disgrace that the US, above all, has turned a blind eye to the disregard of human
> rights shown by israel for so long.

The lack of proper punctuation, capitalisation, etc. in the comment clearly indicates that the author is not bothered about correct formatting, etc.. Hence nothing can properly be adduced from any particular usage in that comment.

Having said that, I certainly was not aware that

> The slash always means *or* (quote from comment by @tchrist above),

and I note that @Jacobm001 disagrees and states that

> On the West Coast of the US, the slash has always indicated an "*and* or *or*"

I do not know whether there is a 'standard' British acceptance of its meaning, but I have always understood it to mean *and* or *or* (or some other alternative combinations when 3 or more items and 'linked' by slashes), with its exact meaning to be adduced from the context, or perhaps even left purposely vague.

Comment: Trevor, +1, but, as John Lawler said "*Or* has several meanings" and no one can say what really it means. For example, consider "You can make payments in June/December", "You can make payments in June as well as in December", "You can make payments in June and in December" and "You can make payments in June or December". What's the difference?

Comment: I know he did (but overlooked it!) and have amended my answer accordingly. All the existing answers appear to be from a US perspective - and even there there is disagreement - so I wanted also to add a UK perspective. And to point out the unreliability of the original source.