# How does 'such as' mean 'of a kind that; like'?

Tags: etymology

Since elementary school, I've known definition 1 (the most common) of **[such as](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/such-as?q=such+as) = for example**. Yet 2 confuses me, so what's an intuitive derivation or etymology behind it?

> 2. **such as** =  Of a kind that; <s>*like*</s> [I crossed this out because how can *like* substitute for **such as** below?]

I did try [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/193400?rskey=Q6ifxI&result=1&isAdvanced=falseER), but my limited English bars me from understanding its many entries with complicated linguistic terms. [The following's an example, but I ask NOT only about legal contexts:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_v_Miller#Judgement)

> I see no rational ground for excluding from conduct capable of giving rise to criminal liability, conduct which consists of failing to take measures that lie within one's power to counteract a danger that one has oneself created, if at the time of such conduct one's state of mind is **such as** constitutes a necessary ingredient of the offence."

Comment: I've asked you this before, and I'll ask here again: please stop asking for etymologies when you want mnemonics. I don't know if you do it because you feel like straight up asking for mnemonics without cover words like *etymology* will get your questions closed as off topic, or if you truly believe the current meaning of a word has some obligation to relate to its origin, but it doesn't matter: both are fallacies. The latter is the etymological fallacy, which you've been pointed at numerous times, and the former is silly because pure  questions of etymology will be question closed as GR.

Comment: With that out of the way (and I hope it's the *last* time I have to ask), here's a way to relate the *of a kind* sense to your *example* sense. An *example* is a *member of a category*, when you produce an example, you are hoping to use it to illustrate something *larger*: you are not focusing on the specific example itself, but *the **kind** of thing it is*. In other words, an *example*, is, literally, *of a kind*, and it is the *kind*, not the *example*, you're concerned with. Dig? "*If the state of mind is **of the type which***" == "*If the state of mind is **an example of***".

Comment: @DanBron Thank you for your comments. Sorry if my question offended you. I forgot to write in this OP that I shall heed the Etymological Fallacy, but I'm interested in not only mnemonics, but also intuitive interpretations or rationalisations that may explain a word's trajectory? Please tell me what you think of this? What are the aptest words that express my objectives?

Comment: I've seen other questions you've asked where you have inserted the phrase "*I heed the etymological fallacy, but...*", and frankly I've found it formulaic (as in *pro forma*), unconvincing, and insincere. Mentioning that you're aware of the fallacy is not some secret password which lets you through the gate and into the paradisical garden where then you can go ahead and commit it! Words mean what they mean and those meanings are recorded in dictionaries. You'll have to use a dictionary to supplement your understanding until you've had sufficient exposure (practice!) to do away with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different "such as" and it is spoken differently. Punctuation that reflects how this one is spoken: "such, as...".

As Dan Bron says, "of the type which".  Or "of a kind|sort that..."

There, "as" is like "that".

*The fracture of the bone was such, as should be attended to immediately.*

*The fracture of the bone was of a sort that should be attended to immediately.*

P.S. In response to the comment:

The vertical bar | is a symbol for 'or'  indicating possible variants.

The comma indicates the natural syntactic pause that  would occur here because "such" is a predicate nominative|nominal in this sentence and is therefore an element of the independent|matrix clause ; "as" introduces a dependent clause that modifies 'such'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please clarify your answer's involvement of 'punctuation'? You split **such as** with a comma in between, and you also inserted a vertical line in "of a kind|sort that..." What do you mean by these?

Comment: See the P.S. Also, please explain why you request that the clarification be appended to the answer?

Comment: Thanks. I happily tried to do so on my profile: Since comments are less readable, please write (edits to) responses only in the Answer, Does this help?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. 1. Am I right that your vertical bar | functions as [the slash's possible meaning](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/120177/50720) of 'or'? 2. Would you please clarify which is `there` in  `There, "as" is like "that"` ?

Comment: I really don't understand your second question.

Comment: I meant to ask for clarification on the antecedent of the deictic pronoun 'There'? You wrote `There, "as" is like "that"`, but where is `There`?

Comment: "There" refers back to examples such as those given by Dan Bron.  If you do an ngram search of `(as would)` from 1700 onward, you'll see, *among* the results, examples of clauses beginning "as would" which modify a nominal in the matrix clause. You'll also see that clauses beginning with "as would" had their heyday in the mid 18th century and have been on the wane since. Which isn't to say you won't still find it in contemporary writing, but it will probably be in fusty legal writing where archaisms abound.