# Can a forward slash be used to describe an item with multiple colors in a list of items?

Tags: slash

The bag consisted of a red/white/blue wallet, a brown/black t-shirt, and tan/brown shoes.

Comment: Is there a red, white and blue wallet or a red wallet, white wallet or blue wallet?

Comment: It's not very formal but might be ok in some situations. It may or may not be ambiguous

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I write "module/theme" or "module / theme"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/should-i-write-module-theme-or-module-theme) The AMA article shows that the slash is used in various different ways, meaning that 'a red/white/blue wallet' could mean 'a wallet coloured red, white and blue' or 'a wallet, which could be red, white or blue'. Not recommended; as Grice advises, 'avoid ambiguity'.

Comment: It’s a single wallet @KillingTime.

Comment: In written English I would assume "a brown/black t-shirt" was either brown or black.

Comment: Right, it’s not formal. It’s a report for the purpose of being able to describe a place or thing from my perspective and a reference if I needed to recall that place or thing. I felt like it was less confusing than writing a lot of “ands” and “commas.” I felt like it’s understandable and more organized. I got the idea from the way retail stores described an item on price tags of clothing and shoes. I am no expert in writing and I am not writing for publication purposes. I just wanted to know if writing it out this way was acceptable.

Comment: @Kelli Wouldn't you say the answer at [Is it commonly accepted using the slash to mean "as well as", rather than "or"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/120177/191178) answers your question or is this about the fact that it appears in a list?

Answer (score 0):

In formal English you would use commas along with "and" and/or "or" to specify lists of possible attributes. To avoid confusion when you have multiple items, use semicolon to distinguish the higher-level grouping.

> The bag consisted of a red, white, or blue wallet; a black or brown T-shirt; and tan or brown shoes.

There's still a minor ambiguity about the shoes: Are they all the same color (tan vs. brown) or a mix of some tan and some brown shoes? Whether it's important to clarify this will depend on the circumstances where this appears.

In some contexts (e.g. the product description in an e-commerce website) you might use a bullet list rather than a grammatical sentence. In that compact format, slashes to separate options would often be acceptable.